# Insert Variable from jQuery Into JSON Schema Markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, schema.org

I'm trying to get the meta description and copy the content of it into some JSON schema markup.
But I'm not sure how to get it to pass the variable into to the JSON structure correctly.

Here's what I was thinking:

```
<script>
      const desc = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
    </script>
    <script type='application/ld+json'>
      {
        "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
        "@type": "LocalBusiness",
        "name": "BizName",
        "telephone": "+1234567890",
        "description": "'+desc+'",
        ....
      }
    </script>
```

I understand that it's not going to fully pass the `desc` variable directly into the JSON markup since it's within separate script tags. I'm just not sure how to combine the two so that it works correctly. Hope that makes sense and open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the schema first then inject it in.

```html
<script>
      const desc = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content").toString();
      var schema = {
        "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
        "@type": "LocalBusiness",
        "name": "BizName",
        "telephone": "+1234567890",
        "description": desc,
        ....
      }      
      var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = "application/ld+json";
        script.text = JSON.stringify(schema);

        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: So looks like I can get it to build out the schema but it looks like it's not injecting the meta content and just generating `'+desc+'` in the description. Not sure if I'm missing something else?

Comment: Ahh good catch. No need to concatenate the `desc` since `var schema` is a javascript object. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Yeah, I kinda figured but I wanted to be sure just in case. Thanks! Seems to be working now.

Comment: Would you provide a version that does not depend on jQuery? Would like to use your solution, but need a 'stand-alone' version that does not require a CDN-call.

Comment: @JayGray - I think if you use `document.querySelector("meta[name='description']").getAttribute("content").toString;` that might work. I have not tested it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't – it's *static* JSON markup, not dynamic JavaScript.

Technically, you *could* dynamically inject a whole new `<script>` tag with all of the Schema JSON, but JavaScript probably* won't get interpreted by software parsing your page for JSON+LD data.

Comment: It will parse. This is how I do it.

Comment: Some consumers may parse it, but not necessarily all of them.

Comment: Google is the only important consumer for this, and Google takes it.

Comment: Assuming the page (and the meta description) is generated by a backend, if OP only needs to read the meta description to generate the LD+JSON, it would still be better to do it all in the backend.

Comment: Awful lot of assumptions you're making. Have you worked with structured data or is this all theoretical?

Comment: We use a similar structure that also is parsed and processed by Google SDTT.